# Firestore doesn't return results in requested order

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have some Firestore requests that I try to get in a  `for loop`, but because Firebase queries are running Async, the results return in random order. Do you have any way to fix it? My code is below.
Thank you in advance!

```java
 for(Feed feed: feedList){
            tasks.add(db.document(feed.getMarker().getPath()).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                    myMarker.add(task.getResult().toObject(SavedMarker.class));
                    System.out.println("Marker: "+ Objects.requireNonNull(task.getResult().toObject(SavedMarker.class)).getDescription());
                    System.out.println("Marker: "+task.getResult().getId());
                }
            }));

            tasks.add(db.document(feed.getUser().getPath()).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                    myUser.add(task.getResult().toObject(Users.class));
                }
            }));
        }

        Tasks.whenAllSuccess(tasks).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<List<Object>>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<List<Object>> task) {
           //Do Stuff

            }
```

For Example:

`IDX` Gives `ResultX`

In my `feedList` I have saved 4 ids like:

```
ID1
ID2
ID3
ID4
```

But when i try to receive their results with the use of a `loop` i get:

```
Result2
Result1
Result3
Result4
```

The order is usually random.

Comment: what order are you expecting them  in?

Comment: The feedList stores document paths in an order, and i try to get the data from these paths in the same order as stored in feedList. But i get something like 1,3,2,4 rather than 1,2,3,4

Comment: Show us what you expect to see, and show us what is happening. You've shared code, but we don't know what you are expecting your code to do. Also if you need something in a particular order, you will need to specify that as part of your query: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data

Comment: @TravisWebb I expect to see the same order of Markers, as it is saved on my "feedList". But it is not. And i can't use orderBy().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> because Firebase queries are running Async, the results return in random order.

The [whenAllSuccess()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Tasks#whenAllSuccess(java.util.Collection%3C?%20extends%20com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task%3C?%3E%3E)) method from the [Tasks](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Tasks) class will always provide the documents from the tasks right into the callback in a `List<Object>`. The order is the same as the order in which the tasks were added to the whenAllSuccess() method. However, if you need an order other than that, then you should either order them on the client in the way you want or create a query based on a field and [order](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data#order_and_limit_data) the documents as needed.